# SipDemo's onReceive() SipAudioCall NullPointerException give

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sip, sip-server

I am Creating incoming call Receive activity by `SipDemo` . My activity has two button "accept call" and "reject call". When i got incoming call then my own activity is open such as
 ----> incoming call class ----> `onReceive()`----> go to my call pick activity.
here is this above two button such as accept and reject call. but when i hit on "accept call" . A `Nullpointer Exception` generate. it is on SipAudiocall incoming;

this is incoming class:-

```
static SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

 Intent startActivity = new Intent(); 
     startActivity.setClass(context, Mycall.class); 
      startActivity.setAction(IncomingCallReceiver.class.getName()); 
      startActivity.setFlags( 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
              | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); 
      context.startActivity(startActivity);   


}

public static void acceptCall() {
    incomingCall.sendDtmf(9);
    try {
        incomingCall.sendDtmf(9);
        incomingCall.answerCall(200);
        //wtActivity.gototimer("i");
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // wtActivity.gototimer("i");
}


public void rejectCaLL() {
    try {
        incomingCall.endCall();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my call pick activity class:-

```
public class Mycall extends Activity {

Button acct;
 IncomingCallReceiver incomingCallReceiver;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Note that none of the preferences are actually defined here.
    // They're all in the XML file res/xml/preferences.xml.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my);

    acct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    acct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IncomingCallReceiver.acceptCall();

        }
    });



}
```

}

This is AndroidManifest.xml :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android.sip">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="SipDemo">
     <service android:name=".MService">

     </service>
  <activity android:name=".WalkieTalkieActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SipSettings" android:label="set_preferences"/>


    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"   android:enabled="true" android:label="Call Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
          <activity android:name=".Mycall"
               >
              </activity> 
           <activity android:name=".Myclass"/> 
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

Please Expert Help me. I has involved this problem since 1 month.

I am wait for your response.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Becouse your

```
IncomingCallReceiver incomingCallReceiver;
```

is null at time of calling it...
If you create a static class you must take care to initiate it maybe in creator-method.

create an abstract class:

```
public abstract class IncomingCallReceiver
```

and change your method to `public static final`

Comment: thank you 4 reply. yes i got it . but how could i solve it . plz suggest

Comment: see edited answer. not sure if that works. you overwrite an interface. I cant see which one. please update your code in question.

Comment: sry for late reply. It is also not working giving me same error .

Comment: Nullpointerexception in incomingcallreceiver class  public static final void acceptCall() {   
        incomingCall.sendDtmf(9); \\the error is in this line. a green color highlight it.

Comment: try this static SipAudioCall incomingCall = new SipAudioCall();